# Create different sign up pages for users with different roles using Devise in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, registration

I have 2 different sign up pages one for normal user and one for fundraiser. for creating user I am using Devise and have normal fields as Name, email and password.
For fundraiser these fields are common with some extra fields so for that I am using this in user.rb

```
attr_accessible :campaign_fundraisers_attributes
has_one :campaign_fundraisers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :campaign_fundraisers, allow_destroy: true
```

this in CampaignFundraiser.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
```

and this in my create_fundraiser.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :class => 'reg',:url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <% resource.build_campaign_fundraisers if resource.campaign_fundraisers.nil? %>
            <%= f.fields_for :campaign_fundraisers do |u| %>
```

here I am able to create user and save data in both the user's and fundraiser's table on form submission but the problem i am facing here is that whenever I get an error (by devise validation) i am getting redirected to the sign-up page for normal user with error messages being displayed there. 
I want a solution so that I get the error message on the same create fundraiser page without being redirected on the normal user's sign up page.

So please suggest any solution for my problem considering I am new to Rails and this is my first post here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `config.scoped_views` like in this documentation said, [config.scoped_views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

then, you can use views based on the role like users/sessions/new or students/sessions/new. If no view is found it will use the defaults at devise/sessions/new